# Parsing and generating JSON

Tags: json, wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica's [list of built-in formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html) is pretty extensive; however, JSON is not on that list. Is there an existing solution for generating and parsing JSON in Mathematica, or are we going to have to roll our own solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

UPDATE: As noted in Pillsy's answer, JSON is a built-in format for Import and Export as of Mathematica 8: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/JSON.html. But, as discussed in the comments, the following seems to be a more robust solution as of Mathematica 10.4.1:

*WARNING: This involves doing an eval (ToExpression) so don't use this to parse strings from untrusted sources.*

First, a really quick-and-dirty partial solution to JSON parsing would be this:

```
ToExpression[StringReplace[json, {"["->"{", "]"->"}", ":"->"->"}]]
```

Ie, just replace square brackets with curly braces and colons with arrows and then eval it.
All that remains is to *not* do those substitutions inside of strings.
(Also need a few more substitutions for null, true, false, and scientific notation.)

There's probably a more elegant solution to the not-within-strings problem, but the first thing to come to mind is to do substitutions like `"{"->"(*MAGICSTRING*){"` and then, after the eval (when comments outside of strings will have disappeared), reverse those substitutions.
(PS: Coming back to this later, I'm actually pretty pleased with the cleverness of that, and it seems to be perfectly robust. Magic strings FTW!)

That's slightly easier said than done but the following JSON parser seems to work:

```
cat = StringJoin@@(ToString/@{##})&;          (* Like sprintf/strout in C/C++. *)
eval = ToExpression;            (* Mathematica function names are too verbose! *)

parseJSON[json_String] := With[{tr = {"["     -> "(*_MAGIC__[__*){",
                                      "]"     -> "(*_MAGIC__]__*)}",
                                      ":"     -> "(*_MAGIC__:__*)->",
                                      "true"  -> "(*_MAGIC__t__*)True",
                                      "false" -> "(*_MAGIC__f__*)False",
                                      "null"  -> "(*_MAGIC__n__*)Null",
                                      "e"     -> "(*_MAGIC__e__*)*10^",
                                      "E"     -> "(*_MAGIC__E__*)*10^"}},
  eval@StringReplace[cat@FullForm@eval[StringReplace[json, tr]], Reverse/@tr]]
```

(`cat` and `eval` are convenience functions. Simply `cat = ToString` would work in this case but I like this more general version that concatenates all its arguments into a string.).

Finally, here's a function to generate JSON (which does need the more general `cat`, as well as another utility function for displaying numbers in a JSON-appropriate way):

```
re = RegularExpression;
jnum[x_] := StringReplace[
  ToString@NumberForm[N@x, ExponentFunction->(Null&)], re@"\\.$"->""]

genJSON[a_ -> b_]  := genJSON[a] <> ":" <> genJSON[b]
genJSON[{x__Rule}] := "{" <> cat @@ Riffle[genJSON /@ {x}, ", "] <> "}"
genJSON[{x___}]    := "[" <> cat @@ Riffle[genJSON /@ {x}, ", "] <> "]"
genJSON[Null]      := "null"
genJSON[True]      := "true"
genJSON[False]     := "false"
genJSON[x_]        := jnum[x] /; NumberQ[x]
genJSON[x_]        := "\"" <> StringReplace[cat[x], "\""->"\\\""] <> "\""
```

Comment: @Pillsy, let us know if this works for you or if you find any bugs or make improvements.  Your answers have been incredibly helpful to me so I was eager to repay the favor!

Comment: I'm now using this for real myself so it's reasonably well-tested at this point. Note the bug fixes just now!

Comment: Mathematica 8 might in principle have import capabilities for JSON, however, it refuses to load a simple small 18 mb .json file (it's running forever). Your function works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: As of Mathematica 10.4.1, the built-in JSON parsing fails with non-ascii unicode strings (like "✔" or "ε") and my little solution from 6 years ago still works like a charm. (Pats self on back.)

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89857/possible-memory-leak-when-importing-json

Comment: This is great to have given the memory leaks in the built-in JSON support (see link above). However, I think that there may be a bug escaping backslashes. Try this: parseJSON@genJSON[{"path" -> "\\\\server\\data\\file.txt"}]

Comment: @gdelfino, thanks for the possible bug report! It looks like ImportString[..., "JSON"] also can't handle those escaping backslashes. This seems silly but Mathematica may just require four backslashes in a row every time you want a literal backslash in an imported string. I know regular expressions are like that.

Comment: @dreeves I am done with the "JSON" import/export format. "RawJSON" is much better as it doesn't leak memory and is faster.

Answer (score 3):

As of Mathematica 8, [JSON is a built-in format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/JSON.html) supporting both Import and Export.

Answer (score 2):

[This guy](http://mathgis.blogspot.com/2010/03/extract-elevation-data-with-google.html) has a clever example of parsing JSON code in Mathmatica

Comment: I think that's just pulling the numbers out a JSON expression though, right?

Comment: yep. That's the great thing about JSON, so easy to parse.

Comment: Yeah, I love JSON.  By "just pulling the numbers out [of] a JSON expr" I meant as opposed to fully parsing it, into an isomorphic nested Mathematica expression.  My answer attempts to do that.