# Can I check with the Stackoverflow API which SO answerers are sleep-deprived?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, stackexchange-api

In [how-do-i-access-the-stackoverflow-api-from-mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745298/how-do-i-access-the-stackoverflow-api-from-mathematica) I outlined how one could use the SO API to get Mathematica to make some interesting reputation graphs of top answerers. Could this API also be used to provide some privacy-invading insights in the answerers' nocturnal habits?

Comment: Only for those users of which you know (and trust) the location.

Comment: ... and their current level of rest. :) I don't think there's and API for tapping the person's brain, but I hear Google and Apple are partnering to build one.

Comment: hahaha, my graph is going to be special. ::grin::

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It looks like you have about two hours sleep per day. I guess a collective of writers hides behind your name. Or is Mr.Wizard = Dr.Jekyll and Mr.Hyde?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Certainly, for instance using this MMA8 code:

```
getActionDates[userID_Integer] :=
 Module[{total},
  total = 
   "total" /. 
    Import["http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/" <> 
      ToString[userID] <> "/timeline?pagesize=1&page=1", "JSON"];
  DateList[# + AbsoluteTime["January 1, 1970"]] & /@ Join @@
    Table[
     "creation_date" /. ("user_timelines" /. 
        Import["http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/" <> 
          ToString[userID] <> "/timeline?pagesize=100&page=" <> 
          ToString[p], "JSON"])
     , {p, Ceiling[total/100]}
     ]
  ]

makeWeekHistogram[userID_Integer] :=
 Module[{dates2Positions},
  dates2Positions = 
   ToExpression[
       DateString[#, {"{", "DayNameShort", "+", "Hour", "+", "Minute",
          "/60./.{Sun->0,Mon->24,Tue->2*24,Wed->3*24,Thu->4*24,Fri->5*\
24,Sat->6*24}}"}]] & /@ getActionDates[userID] // Flatten; 
  Histogram[dates2Positions, {1}, "Count", 
   GridLines -> {Table[24 i, {i, 1, 6}], None}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial-Bold", FontSize -> 16}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
      None}, {{{12, "Sun"}, {24 + 12, "Mon"}, {2 24 + 12, 
        "Tue"}, {3 24 + 12, "Wed"}, {4 24 + 12, "Thu"}, {5 24 + 12, 
        "Fri"}, {6 24 + 12, "Sat"}}, None}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Day of week", "Number of actions", 
     First["display_name" /. ("users" /. 
         Import["http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/" <> 
           ToString[userID], "JSON"])], ""}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0]
  ]

   makeDayHistogram[userID_Integer] :=
 Module[{dates2Positions},
  dates2Positions = 
   ToExpression[DateString[#, {"Hour", "+", "Minute", "/60."}]] & /@ 
     getActionDates[userID] // Flatten; 
  Histogram[dates2Positions, {1}, "Count", 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
      None}, {Table[{i + 0.5, i}, {i, 0, 20, 5}], None}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial-Bold", FontSize -> 16}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Hour", "Number of actions", 
     First["display_name" /. ("users" /. 
         Import["http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/" <> 
           ToString[userID], "JSON"])], ""}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0]
  ]
```

Of course, we only have server time and dates, but the pattern should tell something about localisation, not? Although... Mr.Wizard... you got no life!

```
makeWeekHistogram[353410]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**
Hourly histogram requested by Mr.Wizard:

[image]

Comment: Could you label your `y-axis`?

Comment: I don't speak Mathematica or SO API. What did you graph? Question and answer and comment creation and edition counts?

Comment: @Martinho I counted what's in the user timelines: posts, edits, comments or so. I haven't filtered anything (probably should do that as badges earned are in there as well). API: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-timelines

Comment: Sjoerd, do one that shows only hours of the day (all week days merged) for me, please.

Comment: By the way, I *did* warn you: "Don't try to figure out what time zone I am on, it will only confound you."

Comment: @Sjoerd: Could you post an mma7 version so that I can play with it?

Comment: @yoda Added frames and frame labels

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Done. Yeah, you triggered me with that remark. Anyway, I'll sign-off now. It's 3 am in my TZ.

Comment: @yoda In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745298/how-do-i-access-the-stackoverflow-api-from-mathematica I provide a bare bones MMA 7 Import for JSON formats. I'm off to bed now.